# Load WPF styles or other Static Resources from an external file or assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, assemblies, styles, resourcedictionary

I have a few WPF applications and I want all my styles to be in a shared assembly instead of declaring them in each application separately.

I am looking for a way so I don't have to change all my `Style="{StaticResource BlahBlah}"` in the existing applications; I just want to add the reference to this style assembly, and delete it from the current application, so it's taken from the assembly.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Referencing an external ResourceDictionary (XAML File):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Referencing an external ResourceDictionary (DLL):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyExternalAssembly;component/MyResources.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: But would you please say how we can override a style which exists in the Resources xaml file in other assembly?
For Example: A style which has Foreground property set and it's a default style (which doesn't have any x:Key). Then I just want change Background property. So I used BaseOn, but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: @amkh, once that style is imported to the scope you can then redeclare and override it creating a new style at a high scope level setting it's `BasedOn` to `{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}` (replacing TextBox with the appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My mistake was that I was creating the Style in an incorrect location while I was using BasedOn.

Comment: What about if a UserControl that will be using that resources is in a Class Library Project and there's no App.xaml?

Comment: @JoanComasFdz You could reference that resource dictionary anywhere. You could even add it to that users control resources. But I think maybe you can reference it in `Themes\Generic.xaml` I didn't try it but it might work.

Comment: @Shimmy Thanks for the answer, but I actually meant "how can I reference it in a WPF UserControl XAML code in a Class Library project where is no "Application.Resources" tag?"

Comment: Refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228875/what-is-so-special-about-generic-xaml) - applies to Silverlight as well. Add your resources in Generic.xaml.

Comment: Important thing is Build Action of your Resource file should be set to Resource, and not Embedded Resource. With Embedded Resource it doesn't work.

Comment: How to reference multiple resource files?

Comment: is there a way to do this without a ResourceDictionary? just loading the external xaml file?