# please explain what is themes and generic.xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, generic.xaml

i noticed that when i create a custom control in visual studio it adds generic.xaml into the Themes folder.

what is the purpose of this folder, what is special about generic.xaml? why when i try to link to my own dictionaries from generic.xaml they do not seem to get picked up by the application?

thanks!
konstantin

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228875/what-is-so-special-about-generic-xaml