# Style referenced in generic.xaml not being applied

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this style in Generic.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="WhiteHyperlink" TargetType="Hyperlink">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

I have this line in the resource dictionary

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WhiteHyperlink}" />
```

And I want to apply it to this:

```
<Textblock Grid.Colum="2" >
    <Hyperlink Command="{StaticResource ExecuteMailAction}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=MailboxID}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MailboxName}" />
    </Hyperlink>
</Textblock>
```

But the formatting is not being applied. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I may be wrong,  but isn't generic.xml for key-less default styles? Use a regular resource dictionary.

Comment: All of the other styles in our generic.xaml have keys and they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up Generic.xaml and it appears that the styles in Generic.xaml only get applied if the control which is being styled does not a default style which is theme dependent. 
( [What is so special about Generic.xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228875/what-is-so-special-about-generic-xaml) )
I'm guessing that `Hyperlink` has a default style dependent on the OS' theme which is why your style is not getting pulled from Generic.xaml. I'd recommend not using Generic.xaml to store your styles but rather creating a separate file to store all your styles (MyStyles.xaml or something like that). Then simply use `ResourceDictionary`s to get the style from that file.

Comment: Your code is styling the text box, I'm trying to style the hyperlink.

Comment: yes I understand that, but the basic logic is still the same. If a style gets applied to one control, it will get applied to another. Like I mentioned in my answer, the reason you are not seeing any changes is probably because the property is being set elsewhere.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the `Hyperlink` element be a child of the `TextBlock` element and not the other way round?

Comment: Edited code so that I'm styling a hyperlink, still works just fine.

Comment: I changed your code to the following and it worked:
<TextBlock> 
    <Hyperlink> 
        <TextBlock Text="BLAH"/> 
    </Hyperlink> 
</TextBlock>
Maybe your binding is incorrect? Look in the output window for binding errors.

Comment: The styling works fine as long as it's in the same file as what I'm styling, where I seem to be getting into problems is when I move the style to a resource file.

Comment: Yes, that is how I have it, I didn't include the extra Textblock tag. Sorry