# Styling all instances of a derived type in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I have a class named `MyWindow` that derives from `Window`:

```
using System.Windows;

public class MyWindow : Window
{
}
```

And I use that class in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<MyWpfApp:MyWindow x:Class="MyWpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
          Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Orange"/>
    </Grid>
</MyWpfApp:MyWindow>
```

And in the `App.xaml` file, I add the following style to override the `Background` property of all `MyWindow` instances:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MyWpfApp:MyWindow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

But this doesn't change anything at all. No style is applied to `MainWindow`.

What should I do so that I can use a global style for all `MyWindow`s?

P.S.: I checked out "[Modern UI](http://mui.codeplex.com/)"s code, I saw that they apply something like the following in their window's constructor:

```
using System.Windows;

public class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        DefaultSyleKey = typeof (MyWindow);
    }
}
```

But if I do this, MainWindow ends up being completely black in the content area. I am guessing that somehow its `Template` property gets overriden, but I don't understand how, and how to make this work.

Comment: [This SO answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1232333/1751090) provides a good explanation of applying default themes used above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have worked it out. Apparently there's a special file you can use named `generic.xaml`.

You need to add your style definitions there and then add that file to a directory called `Themes`.

WPF will end up using that as a fall back: `Themes\generic.xaml`

Comment: where is that file located? Thanks :)

Comment: You need to create it yourself.

Comment: Oh. I thought by "there's a special file you can use named generic.xaml" that it already exists.

Comment: It's a special file you can use, but it doesn't exist. You need to create it. Maybe the better wording would be "there's a special file name you can use".