# WPF Custom window invisible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have this structure:

[image]

**LightWindow.cs**

```
namespace ScreenToGif.Controls.LightWindow
{
    public class LightWindow : Window
    {
        static LightWindow()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LightWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LightWindow)));
        }
     //...
    }
 }
```

**Recorder.xaml**

```
<lightWindow:LightWindow x:Class="ScreenToGif.Windows.Recorder"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:lightWindow="clr-namespace:ScreenToGif.Controls.LightWindow"
</lightWindow:LightWindow>
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:lightWindow="clr-namespace:ScreenToGif.Controls.LightWindow">

<!-- Window style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type lightWindow:LightWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type lightWindow:LightWindow}">
<!-- closing tags omitted -->
```

### Problem:

The `Recorder` window opens up invisible. In my test project (a dll with the custom window inside being used in another project), the window shows up correctly.

The only thing that shows up is the internal grid of the `Recorder` window if I remove the `OverrideMetadata` call (not what I want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to make to work:**

[image]

Move the `Themes` resource to the root folder of the project.

Comment: That't pretty important and known fact about `Generic.xaml` file, read about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228875/what-is-so-special-about-generic-xaml