# overriding styles defined in generic.xaml results in merged style

Tags: wpf, xaml, generic.xaml

I have a control with a style defined in a separate resource dictionary and use the generic.xaml magic to apply it.

If I understand the lookup mechanism described on msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms750613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the generic.xaml is used after the application resources, but adding a style for MyWindow will result in the style from generic.xaml + the style defined in App.xaml.

Here is my code:

Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type test:MyWindow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Window}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro" />
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="Default!" />
   </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type test:MyWindow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Window}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="HotPink" />
         </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

The window will have a pink background (from the application.resource style) and "Default!" as title from the generic.xaml style.

Why doesn't wpf stop searching for a style at the application level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because default (theme) styles are treated differently from normal styles.

Consider the [Dependency Property lookup precedence list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list):

> 1. *Property system coercion.*
> 2. *Active animations.*
> 3. *Local value.*
> 4. *TemplatedParent properties.* Triggers and property sets from the TemplatedParent.
> 5. *Implicit style.* A special case for the `Style` property. Here, the `Style` property is filled by any style resource with a key that matches the type of that element. **This lookup does not proceed into the themes**.
> 6. *Style triggers.* Triggers within styles from page or application.
> 7. *Template triggers.*
> 8. **Style setters.**
> 9. **Default (theme) style.**
> 10. *Inheritance.*
> 11. *Default value from dependency property metadata.*

When WPF is deciding the value for `MyWindow.Style`, it goes through the precedence list and settles on using "5. implicit style" to assign it. So then it finds a matching style in App.xaml and uses that. If you inspect MyWindow's properties at runtime, you should indeed see that `MyWindow.Style` is set to the one from App.xaml. So, WPF actually *does* stop searching for a style at the application level.

It's just that because of the `DefaultStyleKeyProperty`, the default style is still there in the DependencyProperty lookup list, albeit at a lower precedence level than the App.xaml style.

In this case, the App.xaml doesn't set the `Title` property, so the DependencyProperty engine falls back to the default style in Generic.xaml to provide a value. So this is why you are getting that merged style behaviour.

Of course, note that this only happens when the Generic.xaml magic [is set up properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228915).