# How can create UI Theme for WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can create UI Theme for WPF application. I find a lot questions how can change theme runtime. But never find how can create. What is the best practice for create theme (if is have best practice). Can somebody give some tutorial to see how is created. What is better to use StaticResource or DynamicResource.

Comment: You're probably interested in [`Themes\Generic.xaml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232333/1187982)

Comment: Thanks for the link Joshua Shearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy answer to this question, but my suggestion would be to download existing themes and study them, experiment with them, and edit them. In fact, you might find it easier to modify an existing theme than start completely from scratch.

Here is one possible source for themes:

https://github.com/Infragistics/InfragisticsThemesForMicrosoftControls

You can find several others by searching Google or browsing NuGet packages with the keywords "WPF themes".

If you have any specific questions on how a particular aspect of a theme works, feel free to search on StackOverflow or ask another question.