# Removing the hover animation on NavigationMenuItem

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I would like the remove the hover animation which is displayed on navigation menu items in the UWP navigation menu. I have looked around, but can't find the default style for the NavigationMenuItem. Not to mention, that creating an entirely new style for something which should be somewhat trivial seems like overkill. Any hints on how this can be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the style of **NavigationViewItem**. You can modify the **PointerOver VisualState** to change the hover animation.

```
<Style  TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemBorderThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
                        <Grid
                        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                        Height="40"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PointerStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelected}" />
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelected}" />
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPressed}" />
                                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Opacity" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaneStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NotClosedCompact" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ClosedCompact">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                            <Setter Target="RevealBorder.Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CompactPaneLength}" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IconStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IconVisible" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IconCollapsed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="IconBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="IconColumn.Width" Value="16" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <!-- Wrap SelectionIndicator in a grid so that its offset is 0,0 - this enables the offset animation. -->
                            <Grid 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Rectangle
                                x:Name="SelectionIndicator"
                                    Width="6"
                                    Height="24"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground}"
                                Opacity="0.0"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Border
                            x:Name="RevealBorder"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                            <Grid Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="IconColumn" Width="48" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Viewbox x:Name="IconBox"
                                         Child="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                Margin="16,12"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: I'll give this a go! Thanks for your help. For curiosity's sake, did you find the default style somewhere, and then just modify that? If so, could you kindly provide the link. Thanks

Comment: You can find it in Generic.Xaml. Search for **TargetType="NavigationViewItem"**

Comment: Generic.Xaml contains all the default styles and colors. Know more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228875/what-is-so-special-about-generic-xaml (Same for UWP or WPF)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the style as said in the previous answer.

Or, maybe, just set the `BorderThickness` to 0 like this:

```
<NavigationView >
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem BorderThickness="0" Content="Item1"/>
        <NavigationViewItem BorderThickness="0" Content="Item2"/>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
</NavigationView>
```