# WPF Shared Resource Problem - No App.xaml, No Shared Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, staticresource

I have run into a little(well big) problem in an application I am working on.

I am working on a module for an application for my company. The application is a WinForm application, but I have been working on a WPF application(not really an application as you will see) that is going to be hosted in this WinForm application when it is complete.

To do this, I am using the WinForm element host, and I have created a "shell" user control, and then other user control windows inside of that shell user control. So it appears as a WPF application, and only uses the WinForm application as its startup project since the WPF application is really only a collection of WPF Controls.

The problem I have ran into is that since I have not created an actual "WPF Application", there is no App.xaml. This has disabled me from using Shared Resources the way I desire, especially XAML shared resources.

Is there a way I can still treat my collection of WPF User Controls as a WPF Application, and somehow use a App.xaml file for my resources. If not, what are my options for using shared resources in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ResourceDictionary` (xaml) file to your project (assuming it's a class library - WPF custom control library), merge it on top of the `Generic.xaml`, then 
you will be able to refer to it and your `StaticResource` will work.

You can also include the resource in the Generic.xaml (or whatever xaml file it is) file itself.

Here is how your current dictionary should look like:

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"   
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1">

  <sys:String x:Key="myString">sdfasdf</sys:String>

  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{StaticResource myString}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I initialized a design time instance of the above control in VS2010 and it showed the text (`Text` is a string DP property I manually added to the `CustomControl1`), which means it reads the `myString` resource.

You can find some more specific info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709087/load-a-resourcedictionary-from-an-assembly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706700/load-wpf-styles-or-other-static-resources-from-an-external-file-or-assembly).